# Delayed alerts on WatchKit?

Tags: swift, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm working on a Swift timer app for Apple Watch. Ideally when the timer runs out it will play a subtle haptic.

The problem is that when the watch screen goes to sleep with my app on top my app is no longer allowed to trigger a haptic.

In researching this I found two possible alternate approaches:

1. Use the user notification API to trigger a full notification. This is not ideal because the purpose of the app is to be subtle, ideally haptic only. I did implement it as a test, and it seems the notification only occurs if my app is not on top. The most common use case for the app will be on top with the watch screen sleeping, meaning neither the haptic nor the notification will play.
2. Start a workout, which allows background apps to trigger haptics. This is not ideal because I assume it burns excessive battery even if I'm not collecting workout data, and the app isn't actually workout-related so Apple probably won't approve it. This is an app that will be used off and on all day.

Is there a third option I'm not seeing? It's pretty simple, I just want to trigger a haptic after a user-selected amount of time passes, even if the watch screen is asleep.

The built-in timer app certainly has no trouble with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible even with iOS app.

A lot of popular alarm clock apps in the app store workaround by playing a silent sound in the background which might be your other alternative.

Comment: Why can the built-in timer app do it? Apple using proprietary APIs?